# Rolling Time Aggregations in SSAS

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, olap

So I've been searching for a good way to calculate rolling quarters in a cube and have had very little progress.

We have one view v_FactScores that we calculate an average by quarter ID. The SQL equivalent of what we do is something along the lines of:

```
SELECT AVG([Score]) Score
FROM v_FactScores fs
INNER JOIN v_DimUser du ON fs.UserID = du.UserID AND fs.Country = du.Country AND fs.quarter1 = du.quarter1
WHERE fs.quarter1 IN (7,8)
```

This would provide an rolling average for leading quarter 8. The next point in the series would be:

```
SELECT AVG([Score]) Score
FROM v_FactScores fs
INNER JOIN v_DimUser du ON fs.UserID = du.UserID AND fs.Country = du.Country AND fs.quarter1 = du.quarter1
WHERE fs.quarter1 IN (8,9)
```

So there is overlap for our quarter 8.

We've created a dimension for our SSAS cube that labels each of the possibilities and looks similar to this:

```
Quarter    RollUpID    Label
1          1           "Leading quarter 2"
2          1           "Leading quarter 2"
2          2           "Leading quarter 3"
3          2           "Leading quarter 3"
3          3           "Leading quarter 4"
4          3           "Leading quarter 4"
```

We then would hope to aggregate on the RollUpID. This doesn't seem to work as we expected though...

I see a lot of solutions using .lag() function in MDX but is there a dimension fact based approach that might work? Otherwise we will need to create three new measures for each metric(Single quarter averages, 2 quarter rolling, and 4 quarter rolling).

Comment: what do the .lag() solutions look like?

Comment: This is a good example of what I'm referring to for the .lag() solutions:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2877/sql-server-analysis-serviceslead-lag-openingperiod-closingperiod-time-related-functions/